# Prove that the circumcentre is the isogonal conjugate

Tags: geometry

> Given $\triangle ABC$ and interior point $P$, reflect $P$ in the sides $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ to $U$, $V$, $W$. Prove that he circumcentre of $\triangle UVW$ is the isogonal conjugate of $P$ in $\triangle ABC$.

I managed a complex bash proof. The main results include
\[q=\frac{\overline p(ab+bc+ca)+p-a-b-c-abc\left(\overline p\right)^2}{abc\left(p\overline p-1\right)^2}\]
and etc.. Now, I want a geometric proof.

Some people say we can use angle chasing and $\cong$ triangles but I don’t know how.

Comment: Nice Geogebra animation [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/sRVERPyd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the circumcentre of $\Delta UVW$. We only show that $\angle BAO = \angle PAC$ (the other angle conditions can be shown in the exact same way). First note that $|AU| = |AP| = |AW|$, so $A$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $UW$. Furthermore $O$, being the circumcentre of $\Delta UVW$, also lies on it and hence we have $\angle UAO = \angle OAW$. Now note that by definition of $U$ and $W$ we have $\angle UAB = \angle BAP$ and $\angle PAC = \angle CAW$, so putting all together we get
\begin{align*}
2\angle UAO &= \angle UAO + \angle OAW = \angle UAW = \angle UAB + \angle BAP + \angle PAC + \angle CAW\\
&=2(\angle UAB + \angle PAC)
\end{align*}
Dividing by 2 and subtracting $\angle UAB$ gives $\angle BAO = \angle PAC$, as desired.